# Push fail for "force:source:push

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am creating an lwc. Below is the js code

```
import { LightningElement, track } from "lwc";
export default class HelloIteration extends LightningElement {
  @track
  contacts = [
    {
      Id: 1,
      Name: "Amy Taylor",
      Title: "VP of Engineering"
    },
    {
      Id: 2,
      Name: "Michael Jones",
      Title: "VP of Sales"
    },
    {
      Id: 3,
      Name: "Jennifer Wu",
      Title: "CEO"
    }
  ];
}
```

And HTML is

```
<lightning-card title="ContactInformation" icon-name="custom:custom14">
  <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
    <template for:each={contacts} for:item="contact">
      <div key={contact.Id}>
        {contact.Name}, {contact.Title}
      </div>
    </template>
  </div>
</lightning-card>
```

When I am trying to push it, an error occurred

```
Error  force-app\main\default\lwc\myFirstWebComponent\myFirstWebComponent.js  bad result: TypeError: Cannot read property 'parent' of undefined 
   at prune (/home/sfdc/tools/lwc/1.3.7-226.6/node_modules/@lwc-platform/sfdc-lwc-compiler/node_modules/@lwc-platform/sfdc-lwc-metadata/dist/template/transform/binding.js:111:17)    at getPrunedPath (/home/sfdc/tools/lwc/1.3.7-226.6/node_modules/@lwc-platform/sfdc-lwc-compiler/node_modules/@lwc-platform/sfdc-lwc-metadata/dist/template/transform/binding.js:121:12)    at elements.forEach.component (/home/sfdc/tools/lwc/1.3.7-226.6y.forEach (<anonymous>)    at Object.transform (/home/sfdc/tools/lwc/1.3.7-226.6/node_modules/@lwc-platform/
ERROR running force:source:push:  Push failed.
```

The linter is throwing the below error

[image]

How to solve the issue?

Comment: The red squiggles that show an error there are a local error, but would not prevent pushing. Can you include the output of `tail ~/.sfdx/sfdx.log` after the push to see what the last few lines are?

Comment: I am not sure how to see the sfdx.log file. There is no such file in my project

Comment: @NoorAShuvo, sfdx fox is suggesting to runn `tail ~/.sfdx/sfdx.log` command from terminal within your project and share the output. That may give some clue about the what is going wrong. Do you see the error in Salesforce when looking at deployment settings? Also I think `@track` is not required anymore after the summer release.

Comment: Additionally try updating sfdx with `sfdx update` command and push again to see if it shows a right error message.

Comment: Maybe it's a copy paste issue but you html should start with template tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The HTML for the component needs to be wrapped in a `<template>` tag. Change the HTML to the following and try re-pushing:

```
<template>
  <lightning-card title="ContactInformation" icon-name="custom:custom14">
    <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
      <template for:each={contacts} for:item="contact">
        <div key={contact.Id}>
          {contact.Name}, {contact.Title}
        </div>
      </template>
    </div>
  </lightning-card>
</template>
```

Comment: Thanks. I missed this <template> tag. I have also updated sfdx cli